# Application of Maximize: The cuboid constrained to the ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry

Since I am a student of Mathematics I enjoy to apply MMA to problems that I have a solid understanding in. The following would be such a problem:

> **Maximize** $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y,z):= 8xyz$ constrained to the ellipsoid $$ E:= \left\lbrace (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2}+ \frac{z^2}{c^2}=1 \right\rbrace $$ where $a,b,c>0$

Under the realistic assumptions that $x,y,z >0$ are all positive (because else wise the cuboid vanishes) this is an easy application by hand on paper with a little help from multivariate Calculus, namely the **Lagrange multipliers**.

After sume juggling with the gradients one obtains the solutions of the maximum  $$x_0= \frac{a}{\sqrt{3}},  \ y_0 = \frac{b}{\sqrt{3}}, \ z_0 = \frac{c}{\sqrt{3}} \implies V_\max=f(x_0,y_0,z_0)= \frac{8abc}{3\sqrt{3}} $$

---

In Mathematica however I struggle to implement this problem:

```
f[x_,y_,z_]:= 8 x y z (* a naive R^3 -> R function *)
```

Then indeed I use the `Maximize` function with the appropriate constraints:

```
Maximize[{f[x,y,z], (x/a)^2+(y/b)^2+(z/c)^2 ==1 && a> 0 && b >0 && c>0}, {x,y,z}]
```

MMA manages to find the same Maximal volume as I did by hand, but for the variables $x,y,z$ it finds very peculiar results:

[image: MMA output for the maximization]

While the volume is correct, I wonder how I get the more realistic $x,y,z$ results as I did by hand.

**Addendum**: More realistically I would have rather defined a function as

```
g[x_ /; x>0, y_ /; y>0, z_ /; z>0]:= 8 x y z
```

But in this case Maximize won't even execute

Comment: `FullSimplify[%, a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0]`, where `%` is your initial result.

Comment: @MichaelE2 if you want you can add this as an answer so I can upvote and accept it. It seems that MMA requires the additional computation of FullSimplify, however the result it gives me is still a bit off, namely $x= - a/ \sqrt{3}, y= -b/ \sqrt{3}, z= c/\sqrt{3}$ I am happy enough however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplifying complicated results sometimes takes a long time, so many *Mathematica* functions do not do so by default.  Or they do it under a time constraint.  Such is the case here, and in addition, `FullSimplify` is needed to simplify the nested `Root` objects.  Note we need to add the constraints as assumptions to get the desired simplification.

```
res = Maximize[{f[x,y,z], (x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 + (z/c)^2 == 1 &&
        a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0}, {x, y, z}]
FullSimplify[res, a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0]
(*
  {(a b c)/(3 Sqrt[3]), {x -> -(a/Sqrt[3]), y -> -(b/Sqrt[3]), z -> c/Sqrt[3]}}
*)
```

P.S.  There are four equivalent answers.  If you want `x`, `y`, and `x` to be all positive, add more constraints.  (*Mathematica* probably found the "first" one in the code above, and since negatives are sorted before positives, we got the solution that starts with two minuses.)

```
res = Maximize[{f[x y z], (x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 + (z/c)^2 == 1 &&
        a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0}, {x, y, z}];
```

Comment: Thank you, especially the first sentence makes indeed a lot of sense.

Comment: @Spaced You're welcome.  I added something, in case you wanted positive coordinates.  It's a bit annoying, but that's because we're human, I suspect.  *M* probably finds the "first" one, and since negatives are sorted before positives, we get the solution will all minuses.